how select the result set of a stored procedure that returns table in snowflake in select statement
below is the stored procedure that we created and it returns table with columns ID, Name
how to Use the result set in snowflake select statement. I tried like below but it did not work. Else please suggest how to create a UDF so that result set can be selected, i have complex python logic inside handler. this is just sample code
select * from  table(test_sp.test_procedure('john'))

create or replace Procedure test_sp.test_procedure(name varchar)   
returns table(id varchar,name varchar)   
language python   
packages = ('pandas','snowflake-snowpark-python')   
runtime_version=3.8   
handler='get_data'  
AS
$$
def get_data(session,name):     
    sql = f'''SELECT    
            ID,NAME    
            FROM TEST_SP.TABLE   
            WHERE NAME = '{name}';  '''   
    df_sql = session.sql(sql )   
    return df_sql   
$$;


A tabular SQL UDF can be used like your example using the select * from table(udf('john')) syntax. Based on your simple example this should work, but likely won't work easily with more complicated code and logic
for procedures this is the primary option in the snowflake docs
call test_sp.test_procedure('john');
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));

you can also use the output with a resultset using the scripting syntax. See Working with resultsets
DECLARE
    res RESULTSET default (call test_sp.test_procedure('john'));
BEGIN
    ...
END;


Thanks For your response, is it possible to create a UDF which has complex python code inside UDF and returns a table using dataframes. because we need to select data from tables and then implement interpolate logic inside UDF. that returns interpolated data as a dataframe

it looks like there are python UDTFs. I haven't used one before though. Docs:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-tabular-functions
